# Is there a way to make Zurb Foundation static / non-responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am asking this because we started a project using Zurb Foundation. However, as we are already building it, we realized that we need more than a responsive framework to cater for mobile devices. (We are planning to build a separate mobile app but it's not yet our immediate concern.)

Hence, it would be better that it just remains static or non-responsive when viewed on any device (meaning the layout remains like what it is on desktop) rather than we handout a flimsy / unusable mobile version. The application has lots of tables and data which cannot be crammed on a mobile device without having to change the entire architecture.

So, back to my question, is there a way to make Zurb Foundation static / non-responsive?

Comment: you could modify foundation's css. once you change the grid system it should be more or less non-responsive

Comment: So you are going to cater whole different website for mobile devices. Why bother about responsiveness then? Those mobile users will never never see it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try [this](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2694)
or remove media's in foundation.min.css

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to do is override the `.row` width.

```
.row {
  width:960px !important;
}
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/XA86W/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
.row {
width: 1200px;
max-width: 1200px;
min-width: 768px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}